# Unable to parse params in create method (file upload)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a create method that is supposed to collect file parameters and save the file in a public folder. I can see the file details being processed through the console, but the first line of my method crashes

Below is the the logs from the console on form submit (i have uploaded two files):

```
Processing by GroupmeetingsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"rsuhfN4HXxd/RG1ZfdmbE2+8T0SC927wC8H5hFI+wYeGUoF9wfWfG3AmiT9nWROauamHM3JsFyS/Hu7fH0RH9g==", "file"=>{"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f9743f68ab0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/c_/cqbnlqbx5lq7vjgf31_wsgvh0000gp/T/RackMultipart20190403-7204-1a88kpp.JPG>, @original_filename="IMG_8009.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[0]\"; filename=\"IMG_8009.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f9743f689e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/c_/cqbnlqbx5lq7vjgf31_wsgvh0000gp/T/RackMultipart20190403-7204-1fjmx9t.jpg>, @original_filename="Cocoa_Front_tribal.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[1]\"; filename=\"Cocoa_Front_tribal.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "locale"=>"en"}
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "bb789076-afd7-43e9-a91c-37ace112183b"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/groupmeetings_controller.rb:53:in `create'
```

The controller looks as following:

```
 def create
    hash = params[:file]
    **files_list = JSON.parse(hash) if hash.is_a?(String)**
    groupmeeting = params[:groupmeeting]
    alpha_start = DateTime.strptime(groupmeeting[:start], "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %P")
    alpha_end = DateTime.strptime(groupmeeting[:end], "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %P")
    @contact_person = User.where(profile: "1", company: current_user.company)
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params.merge(start: alpha_start, end: alpha_end))
    Dir.mkdir("#{Rails.root}/public/"+@event.id.to_s)
    files_list.each do |pic|
      File.rename( "#{Rails.root}/"+pic, "#{Rails.root}/public/"+@event.id.to_s+'/'+File.basename(pic))
      product.pics.create(name: pic)
    en

    if @event.save
      redirect_to events_path, notice: "OK! Event is created."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Does anybody knows how to process the files. I am using the following tutorial but it seems to be missing a lot :
https://www.sitepoint.com/asynchronous-multiple-file-upload-with-rails-and-dropzone-js/

Comment: Specifically to line 53 of the groupmeetings_controller, what code is there?

Comment: line 53 is: files_list = JSON.parse(hash) if hash.is_a?(String)

Comment: What happens if you remove hash.is_a?(String) ? Your hash *is* a hash

Comment: Without the hash.is_a?(string) i have `TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String):app/controllers/groupmeetings_controller.rb:50:in `create'
with line 50 being: files_list = JSON.parse(hash)

Comment: Can someone see something incorrect in my code or a suggestion please? I need to present the project in 3hr :(

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. If I was in your position; I would attach a debugger such as byebug to find out what are in the variables on line 53. One of them is nil - find out why and your problem is solved.